# Centered Bootstrap grid with a twist

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to create a 12 cols bootstrap grid like this below.

Light blue i the header, green is the body, and the orange is the footer. Grey is background.

I need it to be centered on the screen, and the 12 cols bootstrap grid is marked with the horizontal light blue stripes.

The designer call it a normal bootstrap grid, but I think it has some twist included.

Any idea to a solution? And could it be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can certainly be done. Just nest the divs so that your striped col-12 grid is within your centered view.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid